# Changing .NET 6 COM host's publisher/other information?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, .net-6.0

I am writing a COM application in C# and I am curious if it is possible to change the VERSIONINFO of a `.comhost.dll` that is generated alongside the one with all the .NET code. So there are two DLL files that are outputted after building, a regular one and a COM host one that you use with `regsvr32`. The regular .NET one has the correct information, as set in the .NET project settings, but the COM host has generic information from Microsoft.

This is because the information of the .comhost.dll is displayed in some areas, such as the IE addons manager, which is misleading as it will state that the publisher is "Microsoft Corporation". I want this to be my name.

[image: Example of the CompanyName being "Microsoft Corporation"]

Although the .NET code (`MyApplication.dll`) has the correct `CompanyName` value, the COM host (`MyApplication.comhost.dll`) still retains this "Microsoft Corporation" value.

Although I haven't discovered a way to set this during compilation, it is possible to manually change the value after building via a tool like Resource Hacker. This is a less than ideal solution, but it can work if there is no better solution.

Comment: Project > Properties > Package > General > Company

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, that's already set. The issue is that it won't apply to the .comhost.dll file.

Comment: That is not a generated file, it is copied from the .NET SDK install and legally owned by Microsoft.  Fairly doubtful that is okay to change it, but ResourceHacker would be the only good way to do so.  Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues) to get the formal response.

Comment: You don't need to modify the comhost (aka 'shim') at each compile. Copy the standard one (from a path like this `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64\7.0.4\runtimes\win-x64\native\comhost.dll`) somewhere, change it to your will with the tool you want (it's not signed on purpose by microsoft as it can be customized https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/COM-activation.md), and then reference it in the .csproj like this in a PropertyGroup (aside `EnableComHosting` for example): `<ComHostSourcePath>c:\mypath\mycomhost.dll</ComHostSourcePath>`

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [Simon Mourier's original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75762286/changing-net-6-com-hosts-publisher-other-information?noredirect=1#comment133651966_75762286):

You don't need to modify the comhost (aka 'shim') at each compile. Copy the standard one (from a path like this `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64\7.0.4\runtimes\win-x64\native\comhost.dll`) somewhere, change it to your will with the tool you want (it's not signed on purpose by Microsoft [as it can be customized](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/COM-activation.md)), and then reference it in the .csproj like this in a PropertyGroup (alongside `EnableComHosting` for example):

```
<ComHostSourcePath>c:\mypath\mycomhost.dll</ComHostSourcePath>
```